# Turning drawing space on iOS device 90 degrees

Tags: ios, transformation, quartz-graphics

I wanted to do something with Quartz  2D which I though should be simple, but turns out not to be :-(

What I try to do is the following. I want to rotate the drawing area by 90 degrees, so that basically anything I draw is rotated 90 degrees as well. Turns out the rotation works ok, but the rectangle I draw starts off screen, and it does not cover the whole height, but only is as heigh as the width (320 pixels) see screenshot.

Here's my code (inside drawRect):

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); //get the graphics context
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0) ;

float width = rect.size.width ;
float height = rect.size.height ;

CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.origin.x +  width / 2,  rect.origin.y + height / 2 ) ; // make rotation point the middle
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, 1.57079633) ; // 90 degrees
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, - height / 2, - width / 2) ; // move x / y back to where they belong


CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, height, width) ;
CGContextFillRect(ctx, myRect) ;
```

The result is as follows:
[image: sccreenshot of iPhone5 Simulator]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, height, width) ;
```

Params are `{x,y,w,h}`

try 
    CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height) ;

also, you should implement a `DEG_TO_RAD` function to help with passing angles into these drawing functions to make your coding easier

```
#define DEG_TO_RAD(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

This

```
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, 1.57079633) ; // 90 degrees
```

becomes

```
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, DEG_TO_RAD(90)) ;
```

Added benefit: You lose the comment and you can increment this value programatically in degrees

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately it does not address the initial problem - which is, that drawing does not fill the whole screen, in fact the output still looks the same.

Comment: It does fill the scree, but you are moving it out of the rendering window.  CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, - height / 2, - width / 2)

is the wrong order too. Width, Height not Height, Width

Comment: ok, now, after your suggested change the output looks like a  bit better, but the rect still does not fill the screen

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When creating the view I mistakenly used width for heigh and vice versa. After I've fixed that all I had to do within the view was the following:

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.origin.x +  width / 2,  rect.origin.y + height / 2 ) ; // make rotation point the middle
CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, DEG_TO_RAD(90)) ;
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, - height / 2, - width / 2) ; // move x / y back to where they belong

CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, height-5, width) ; // height determines width and width is height

CGContextClipToRect(ctx, myRect) ; // prevent lines being draws outside
```

From that onwards I use only myRect as a reference for all drawing operations.
And here's the result.
[image]